# An Alternative Solution to a List Manipulation Example

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming, education

Is there any way to write a code that has a **function** include **Block[ ]** and **Do[ ]** loop instead of my code?

Here is my code:

```
(* m = Maximum members of "list" *)
list = {{12, 9, 10, 5}, {3, 7, 18, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 3},
   {4, 5, 6, 2}, {1, 13, 1, 1}};
m = {};
Do[
  AppendTo[m, Max[list[[All, i]]]];
  , {i, 1, Length[list[[1]]]}];
m
(*{12,13,18,6}*)
```

Comment: You can get the same result using  Max/@Transpose@list

Comment: @J42161217 Thank you, I just wanted to write it by using functions.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Why are you forced to use those 2 functions?

Comment: @user6014 No, Its just an alternate code to do same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[l_List] := Block[{m={}, i=1}, Do[AppendTo[m, Max[l[[All, i++]]]], {Length @ l[[1]]}]; m]

f[list]
```

> {12, 13, 18, 6}

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use your code try

```
F[list_] := Block[{m}, m = {};
Do[AppendTo[m, Max[list[[All, i]]]];, {i, Length[list[[1]]]}];m]

F[list]
```

otherwise you can use this function

```
F[list_]:=Max/@Transpose@list
```

Comment: As `Do` scopes its iterator, there is no need to scope the `i`...